# How to goto the next line in UITextField?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit

In NSTextField all I have to do is add '\n'  i.e..  @"hello\nthere"  will be 2 lines:

```
hello
there
```

I tried this in UITextField and it all stayed on one line

```
hello there
```

What do I need to do to make text go to the next line?

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use UITextView, which supports multiple line text: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html

UITextField only supports a single line: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html

Answer (score 3):

If you are supplying the text and the user doesn't need to edit it, use **UILabel**, and set it's property

```
 numberOfLines = 2;
```

If the user does need to edit it, use a **UITextView**, and set it's frame.size.height to be at least twice the size of the font size you're using.

Answer (score 2):

UITextFields are one-line controls. They can't display multiple lines of text. Use UITextView for that purpose.